# Difference of Validator and PyValidator

Tags: wxpython

what's the different of  `wx.Validator` and `wx.PyValidator`?
And how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyValidator is a subclass of wx.Validator. According to the [docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.PyValidator-class.html), PyValidator is a proxy for wx.Validator, so I don't think there really is a difference per se. However, most examples use the Py version. There's a [wiki page](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Validator%20for%20Object%20Attributes) on the wxPython website on this topic that you should read. You can also read about them in the new Phoenix [docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/validator_overview.html#validator-overview) or check out the example in the wxPython demo package.